# ignored top level const qualifiers for value types in partial function specialization

Tags: c++, c++11

The following errors due to the `const int` specialization:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename T> void g(T val)
{
    cout << "unknown" << endl;
}

template <> void g(int && val)
{
    cout << "int &&" << endl;
}

template <> void g(const int && val)
{
    cout << "const int &&" << endl;
}

template <> void g(int & val)
{
    cout << "int &" << endl;
}

template <> void g(const int & val)
{
    cout << "const int &" << endl;
}

template <> void g(int val)
{
    cout << "int" << endl;
}

template <> void g(const int val)  //redefinition here
{
    cout << "const int" << endl;
}

int main() {}

error: redefinition of 'g'
template <> void g(const int val)
                 ^
```

Why are `T&` and `T&&` distinct from `const T&` and `const T&&` but `T` is not distinct from `const T`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because top-level const-ness of function parameters is an implementation detail of the function.  For example, the following is valid:

```
// Prototype
void foo(int c);

// Implementation
void foo(int const c) { ... }
```

Since the argument is passed by value, the caller doesn't really care whether the function is going to modify its own private copy.  Therefore, top-level const-ness is not part of the function signature.

Note that this only applies to top-level const-ness!  `int` and `int const` are equivalent in a function prototype, as are `int *` and `int * const`.  But `int *` and `int const *` are not.

Comment: right, thanks. and this applies anytime an object is copied. top level const-ness is ignored since the copied from object is not changed. E.g. `const int ci; int i; i=ci;`

Comment: But note that you can say `template<> void g<const int>(const int val) {}` and it works. It is only the function type that will be `void(int)` and hence since the function type is used to deduce `T`, `T` would become `int`. But if you provide it explicitly like that, it works.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub Yes, however in order to use this I must explicitly specify the template type in the function call . `int i=1; const int ci=i; g<const int>(ci);` Otherwise `g(ci);` calls `void(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

When using arguments there are a few things to take into consideration, A: Not passing an arguement by reference is creating its own new variable, and B: Passing by reference is using the same variable as the argument with a different name

This is important because:

```
void doStuff (const int x)
{
    //x is its own constant variable
}
```

Whereas

```
void doStuff (const int& x)
{
    //because x is the same variable that was used when calling this function
    //x can be modified outside of this function, but not inside the function
    //due to the const modifier
}
```

The const modifier on the 2nd function allows you to do things like this:

```
int main ()
{
    const int x = 10;
    doStuff(x)
}
```

References are used to modify a variable in another function and to save memory on the stack, this saves memory because it uses a pointer rather than a newly created variable, so anything larger than an int will save memory by calling using a reference even if you arent modifying it in the function

Now if i am correct the && operator should not be used in an argument because this is a boolean operator and does not modify the argument type.  It should only be used in conditions but wouldnt create a syntax error when compiling (compiler thinks its a reference of type [type] &) but that does nothing to the way the variable is used besides taking slightly longer for the computer to process

Comment: c++ compilation is context sensitive so the compiler sees `&&` in the context of a  function parameter list. In a c++11 compliant compiler this signifies the argument is an "r-value reference" type.